# Is there a way to classify a set of data as a whole via Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, classification

I'm currently dealing with a classification task on a CT dataset. In CT datasets, multiple slices belong to one single patient, while setting up my dataset, I arrange my data as follows:
dataset/0/patient_1/1.png,2.png...
dataset/0/patient_2/1.png,2.png...
I wonder is there a way to let my network to classify by patient instead of by slices?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Each slice is a 2D image, while for each patient you have a 3D volume of CT voxels.
If you want to work per-patient, rather than per-slice, you'll need to organize your data to output batches of 3D information (of shape `batch`x`channel`x`depth`x`height`x`width`) and make your model process 3D information (e.g., using `Conv3D` instead of `Conv2D`)

Comment: Thanks for your great advice! Considering my limited computing resources, it may be hard for me to use 3D networks, so I'm looking for a 2D solution.

Comment: As long as you can fit one volume in your GPU, you can [accumulate gradients](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-do-we-need-to-set-the-gradients-manually-to-zero-in-pytorch/4903/20)